# Django Issues with Multi Authentication in Tasty Pie SessionAuthentication Not Working

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-permissions

I'm trying to get '**Multi Authentication**' to work in Tasty Pie. So far **ApiKeyAuthentication()** works making external calls, but when I use the API on my own Django site '**SessionAuthentication**' (the same site the API is hosted on) it fails the authentication despite the user being logged in.

**Have I missed something?**

Tasty Pie Doc on Multi Authentication [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#multiauthentication)

**My Resource:**

```
class CommonMeta:
    """
    Based Mata to which all other model resources extend/inherit.
    """
    # MultiAuthentication is used here, wraps any number of other authentication classes,
    # attempting each until successfully authenticating.
    authentication = MultiAuthentication(ApiKeyAuthentication(), SessionAuthentication())
    authorization = UserObjectsOnlyAuthorization()



class ContactResource(MultipartResource, ModelResource):
    class Meta(CommonMeta):
        queryset = Contact.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'contacts'
        list_allowed_methods = ['get']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post']
        excludes = ['id']
```

**My AJAX request:**

```
 $.ajax({
          url: '/api/v1/contacts/' + id + "/",
          type: 'PUT',
          data: {"company": "test"},

          // On success.
          success: function(data) {
            alert('Load was performed.');
          }

       });

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's working as it should, you may have just missed one important note on Tasty Pie docs

```
It requires that the user has logged in & has an active session. 
They also must have a valid CSRF token.
```

You need to pass a valid CSRF token for SessionAuthentication to work.

Here is an example:

First setup a function to send a csrftoken with every ajax request

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
```

Then on your ajax setup:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
            crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
                }
            }
        });
```

Last in your template don't forget to include the **{% csrf_token %}** tag!